# RPi - accessing a folder and then running a python script on startup

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want my RPi to open run a python webserver and open Chromium to access it.
It should do it automaticaly on startup.

BUT

When I run the script via command
`$ sudo python3 /home/sps-training/python/webserver.py`
and open localhost on chromium, it says that it can't access HTML file in another folder (/deploy)
but when I open the dictionary first
`$ cd /home/sps-training/python/`
and then open the script
`$ python3 webserver.py`
it suddenly works!

So there are 2 possible solutions
The first one is to make it work by using:
`$ sudo python3 /home/sps-training/python/webserver.py`

The second one is to automatically access directory and the start the script

Right now I'm using /etc/profile to run it on startup (I just wrote at the last line with & on the end of the line)

Thanks a bunch for every advice!

btw sorry for grammar

Comment: `webserver.py` is looking for files in the current directory, not the directory containing the script. Change it to use an absolute path for the directory containing the files.

Answer (score 1):

Like Barmar said. It sounds like the issue you're running into is a working directory vs. current directory problem. When you run `sudo python3 /home/sps-training/python/webserver.py`  you are launching webserver.py in the directory `/` and if it looks for "deploy/index.html" it's going to look in `/deploy/index.html`. However, when you cd into `/home/sps-training/python/` and then run `python3 webserver.py` the working directory is now `/home/sps-training/python/` and it will look for `deploy/index.html` in `/home/sps-training/python/deploy/index.html`

The best solution is to edit the python script to use absolute file paths.

Barring that, you need to cd to the correct working directory every time.